# What is my son studying at school?

Tags: knowledge, crosswords, history

My eight-year-old was recently given a homework assignment to create a small crossword puzzle that demonstrated what he'd learned while studying his class's History topic this term. So we put our heads together and did just that...

When he handed in his work, the teacher read through the list of clues and pointed out that my son might not have understood the homework brief. My son just smiled sweetly and told the teacher to solve it and see. Suffice to say that afterwards the teacher was actually quite impressed!

> **TASK: Solve the crossword and tell me: What period of history was my son studying at school this term?**

[image: Crossword to be solved]

> **Across:**
> 5: Saša ___, Charlton Athletic goalkeeper, 1997-2002 (4)
> 7: Finger-like projections that line the small intestine (5)
> 8: Furiously angry (5)
> 9: Socialise (e.g.) at a party (3)
> 10: Prefix: "Partway through" (3)
> 12: Courteous and polite (5)
> 14: Imitate (5)
> 15: Capital of Timor-Leste (4)
>
> **Down:**
> 1: Skirt with hem halfway between ankle and knee (4)
> 2: Precedes Kim, Nas X or Wayne (3)
> 3: Cover (3)
> 4: Not sharp, spicy or bitter (4)
> 6: Line of cars manufactured by Honda (5)
> 7: Producing strong, clear images in the mind (5)
> 9: Mariah Carey album, *The Emancipation of ___* (4)
> 11: Britney Spears hit, *Oops!... ___ It Again* (1,3)
> 12: UK plainclothes police force branch (1,1,1)
> 13: *Lord of the Rings* actress, ___ Tyler (3)

Comment: FYI This is a *partly* true story. The history topic and the homework assignment were genuine. The actual crossword presented here, however, is what I *suggested* to my son he should do. However, he was *not* up for it and thought it was 'weird'... so this puzzle really is my imagining of how I would have *liked* this whole scenario to play out in my ideal world...! Maybe next time...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say maybe

> Ancient ROMAN history

As the entire puzzle is composed of

> ROMAN numerals!
>  [image]

Comment: Correct :) +1 and a checkmark for you - hope you also appreciated the choice of font for the numbers in the grid!!

Comment: Ha, very clever. Yesterday my six year old for no particular reason started singing"A, 1, B, 2..." He made it to 26... I guess he is going to be a puzzler!